# Python 3.6 - Search word in a list that contain dictionary that containt dictionary in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.6

I tried to do a simple title but I'm a bit lost with this one.

I'm using a python module Python-HPILO in order to gather some information like Hard Drive Disk and DIMM details on HP Blades, this is working.

Example :

```
import hpilo
ilo = hpilo.Ilo('10.0.0.1', 'USER', 'PASSWORD')
health = ilo.get_embedded_health()
logical_drives = (health['storage']['Controller on System Board']['logical_drives'])
print(logical_drives)
```

Result (anonymized) :

`[{**'label': '01', 'status': 'OK', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'fault_tolerance': 'RAID 1/RAID 1+0', 'logical_drive_type': 'Data LUN', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'physical_drives': **[{**'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', **'marketing_capacity': '450 GB'**, 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'**}**, {'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'marketing_capacity': '450 GB', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'**}]}]`

I would like to collect the value of marketing_capacity, which is 450GB here. I found some other topics related to incursive search in list or dict but I were not able to make it work with this specific listed-dictonary-listed-dictonary thing.

Does anyone have a simple way/function to do research in this kind of list ?

Comment: How do you deal with repeats? For example, the second dictionary has 500GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through it like any other list:

```
drive_data =  health['storage']['Controller on System Board']['logical_drives']

for logical_drive in drive_data:
    for physical_drive in logical_drive['physical_drives']:
       print(physical_drive['marketing_capacity'])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. With this I'm able to find  our generally used two disk on blades.

Answer (score 2):

You can access that variable by

```
logical_drives[0]['physical_drives'][0]['marketing_capacity']
```

> '450 GB'

---

If the nesting of your dictionary changes you can unwrap both the lists and dictionaries in your list, and then extract the desired value

val = 'marketing_capacity'

```
def unwrap(dic):    
    temp = {}
    for i in dic:
        if type(i) in [list, dict]: temp.update(unwrap(i))
        elif type(dic[i]) in [list, dict]: temp.update(unwrap(dic[i]))
        else: temp.update({i: dic[i]})
    return temp

temp = [{'label': '01', 'status': 'OK', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'fault_tolerance': 'RAID 1/RAID 1+0', 'logical_drive_type': 'Data LUN', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'physical_drives': [{'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'marketing_capacity': '450 GB', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'}, {'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'marketing_capacity': '450 GB', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'}]}]
x = unwrap(temp)
x['marketing_capacity']
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about dictionaries in lists. You already know how to look up nested values - just continue the same principle.

```
print(logical_drives[0]['physical_drives'][0]['marketing_capacity'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import hpilo
ilo = hpilo.Ilo('10.0.0.1', 'USER', 'PASSWORD')
health = ilo.get_embedded_health()
logical_drives = (logical_drives[0]['physical_drives'][0]['marketing_capacity'])
print(logical_drives)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get *all* values for 'marketing_capacity' I would use a generic list comprehension.

```
lst = [{'label': '01', 'status': 'OK', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'fault_tolerance': 'RAID 1/RAID 1+0', 'logical_drive_type': 'Data LUN', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'physical_drives': [{'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'marketing_capacity': '450 GB', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 1', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'}, {'label': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'status': 'OK', 'serial_number': 'SXXXXXX', 'model': 'YYYYYY', 'capacity': '419 GiB', 'marketing_capacity': '450 GB', 'location': 'Port 1I Box 1 Bay 2', 'fw_version': 'HPD9', 'drive_configuration': 'Configured', 'encryption_status': 'Not Encrypted', 'media_type': 'HDD'}]}]

res = [d2.get('marketing_capacity') for d2 in d.get('physical_drives') for d in lst]

# ['450 GB', '450 GB']
```

Note this will work for arbitrary dictionaries in your outer list, as well as arbitrary dictionaries in your inner list.